# When writing an application, finish the functions first, then optimize?

Tags: c#, .net, performance

Donald Knuth said that "premature optimization is the root of all evil", and I gradully believe the saying.

So can I put it that when writing an application, we should concentrate on completing the functions, **without concerning performance issue, until we cannot bear the low performance**?

I'm afraid that if I use a wrong pattern many times which slows down the application, as a result fix the issue may consume a considerable amount of time. Should I test the performance of the pattern before widely using it?

The pattern I mentioned may refer to use Linq or for-loop, use `Delegate.BeginInvoke`, `Parallel.For`, or `Task<T>`,  dispose `IDisposable` or just ignore it, etc.

Any refernece materials are all welcomed.

Comment: Try Posting [Here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: Do not misinterpret that quote as a free pass for bad code!

Comment: In general: Make it work, then make it fast. If you try to make it fast, you often end up with something that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the spirit of Knuth's quote about premature optimization, as it can cause code to become overly complex and unwieldy too early in development, impacting both the quality of the code and the time needed to complete a project.

Two concerns I have about your post:

You should have a sense about whether or not your function/algorithms can theoretically scale/perform or not to meet your requirement (e.g. the O complexity of your solution -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms )

The patterns you mention are actually concrete implementation items, only some of which are related to performance, e.g.

- Parallel.For/Task - these are useful for gaining performance on multi-core systems
- IDisposable - this is for resource management related, and not something to be avoided
- Linq vs. for-loop - this can be a point-optimization, but you'll need to benchmark/assess your use case to determine which is best for you (e.g. Linq can be moved to PLinq in some cases for parallelism)
- Delegate.BeginInvoke - a non-optional component of thread synchronization

Comment: Agree: first, make it work, then make it work fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

Never code without concern for performance.
Code for performance up until the code would get more complex (e.g. parallel).
But with C# 5.0 even parallel is not complex.
If you have some calls you think might need to optimize then design for that.
Design the code so optimization does not change the interface to the method.

There is speed, memory, concurrency (if a server app), reliability, security, and support.
Clean code is often the best code.

Don't get crazy until you know you have a performance problem but don't get sloppy.

In answering another question on SO I told the person they did not need a DataTable and  DataReader would be faster with less memory.  Their response was it still runs in 1/2 a second I don't care.  To me that is sloppy code.

@JonhSanders  I disagree that "Code for performance up until the code would get more complex" will cause either bugs or incomplete.  For me coding for performance is not the same as optimize.  First pass on anything but throw away code I code for performance - nothing exotic just best practices.  Where I see potential hot spots that I might need to come back and optimize I write with optimization in mind.   P.S. I agree on closing the question.

Comment: Do you feel it's helpful to have fast code that does not work, or which is incomplete?